# Getting glibc detected error when trying to delete parts of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, glibc

When I run the following code, I keep getting a glibc detected error when I try to use the delete[] I[i] command (always on the last run through of the loop). Right before the loop that tries to delete I[i], I print out the values in the last row of I, and it shows up exactly as it is supposed to, so I don't think the issue has to do with the loop being too large. What am I doing wrong? (I've included every line of code where **I shows up).

EDIT 2: The entirety of the error message is:

```
*** glibc detected *** getParams: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x086861f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b591)[0x271591]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cde8)[0x272de8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x275ecd]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0x1cb741]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1d)[0x1cb79d]
getParams[0x804ac78]
getParams[0x8048943]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x21cbd6]
getParams[0x8048731]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-001f9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 396979     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
001f9000-001fa000 ---p 000e9000 08:01 396979     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
001fa000-001fe000 r--p 000e9000 08:01 396979     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
001fe000-001ff000 rw-p 000ed000 08:01 396979     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
001ff000-00206000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00206000-00359000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11272305   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00359000-0035a000 ---p 00153000 08:01 11272305   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
0035a000-0035c000 r--p 00153000 08:01 11272305   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
0035c000-0035d000 rw-p 00155000 08:01 11272305   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
0035d000-00360000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0074f000-00773000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11272350   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
00773000-00774000 r--p 00023000 08:01 11272350   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
00774000-00775000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 11272350   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
00a7b000-00a7c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00d1c000-00d37000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11276409   /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00d37000-00d38000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 11276409   /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00d38000-00d39000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 11276409   /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00ec8000-00ee5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11272275   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00ee5000-00ee6000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 11272275   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00ee6000-00ee7000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 11272275   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
08048000-0804c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4720134    /home/rkappiyo/Dropbox/xingResearch/finalMatlab/getParams
0804c000-0804d000 r--p 00003000 08:01 4720134    /home/rkappiyo/Dropbox/xingResearch/finalMatlab/getParams
0804d000-0804e000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 4720134    /home/rkappiyo/Dropbox/xingResearch/finalMatlab/getParams
08686000-086a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7600000-b7621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7621000-b7700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b774f000-b7751000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7762000-b7765000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfcd4000-bfce9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

EDIT: I've changed it to include the entirety of the code.

```
void invertMatrix(double **mat, int size) {
//index variables used for looping
int i, j, k;

//L and U are the LU decomposition of mat
double **L, **U;

//invMat is the inverted matrix, which will be stored in mat
double **invMat;

//I is the identity matrix
double **I;

L = new double *[size]; //allocation 1

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    L[i] = new double[size]; //allocation 2

U = new double *[size]; //allocation 3

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    U[i] = new double[size]; //allocation 4

//compute the LU decomposition of mat and store in L and U
LUDecomp(mat, size, L, U);

invMat = new double *[size]; //allocation 5

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    invMat[i] = new double [size]; //allocation 6

I = new double *[size]; //allocation 7

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    I[i] = new double [size]; //allocation 8

    for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if(i == j)
            I[i][j] = 1;
        else
            I[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    invMat[i][0] = I[i][0] / L[0][0];

    for(j = 1; j < size; j++) {
        invMat[i][j] = I[i][j];

        for(k = 0; k < j; k++)
            invMat[i][j] -= L[j][k] * invMat[i][k];

        invMat[i][j] /= L[j][j];
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    mat[i][size - 1] = invMat[i][size - 1] / U[size - 1][size - 1];

    for(j = size - 2; j > -1; j--) {
        mat[i][j] = invMat[i][j];

        for(k = j + 1; k < size; k++)
            mat[i][j] -= U[j][k] * mat[i][k];

        mat[i][j] /= U[j][j];
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    delete[] L[i]; //free allocation 2
    delete[] U[i]; //free allocation 4
    delete[] invMat[i]; //free allocation 6
    delete[] I[i]; //free allocation 8
}

delete[] L; //free allocation 1
delete[] U; //free allocation 3
delete[] invMat; //free allocation 5
delete[] I; //free allocation 7
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect in this code. You'll have to post something more complete.

Comment: Since you've gone to the trouble of simplifying the code, it would be worth the little extra effort to get the edited code to a compilable state, and seeing if the problem still happens then.

Comment: As a general point, it would be sensible to factor out the code for maintaining the memory in the matrix into a separate class from the logic for calculating an inverse. That way you can test the (relatively simple) memory-management class more easily.

Comment: @HighCommander4: I've now posted the entirety of the code. @Tim Martin: I actually did try that, and the error did indeed persist.

Comment: I'm not sure a separate class is warranted in this case, but the allocate-a-matrix and deallocate-a-matrix code really needs to be its own functions.

Comment: I can't see anything blatantly wrong, just annoying things like code duplication, so I'm wondering about the `LUDecomp(mat, size, L, U);` function.

Comment: Is `LUDecomp` writing beyond the bounds of one of its arguments?  What is its signature?  Does it want something other than an array-of-arrays?

Comment: Also, if you are running on a supported system, try using Valgrind (http://www.valgrind.org/) on your code.

Comment: LUDecomp(mat, size, L, U) does nothing to mat, and returns the correct values for L and U. I've tested this code and it seems to be working. As far as writing beyond the bounds goes, I'm fairly certain it doesn't.

Comment: What is the **complete** error message?

Comment: I've edited my question to include exactly what my terminal prints out when I run the code.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how `mat` was allocated; can you check that all the allocations for that are correct?

Comment: Also, @Mike DeSimone and Jeremiah Willcock, I copied this code into a test.cpp file and compiled without the LUDecomp method being used at all, and I still got the same error occuring at the same time. @Mike Seymour, I also tried this code after removing any and all references to mat, still same problem at the same location.

Comment: Have you tried running under Valgrind?

Comment: I copied the code you posted and removed the call to LUDecomp, and ran it with a simple 3x3 matrix without seeing any error messages. I agree with Daniel, valgrind is definitely the best tool here.

Comment: This almost certainly means that something (not in the code you've shown, as far as I can see) is writing beyond the end of a block of memory, or writing to memory after it has been deleted. I also suggest Valgrind to track down this kind of thing.

Comment: Well, this is somewhat embarrassing... I'm not sure why my test.cpp file (the one where I removed references to just about everything other than I) errored out, but the reason the main code wasn't working is because I was a moron... I used for(i = 0; i < size; i++) mat[i] = new double[i]; instead of mat[i] = new double[size];. After fixing this stupidity, the code works. Sorry for being so dense earlier. Also, at those who suggested valgrind, I have it and have tried using it, but have no idea how to interpret the output, are there any tutorials available for someone as dumb as myself?

Comment: I take it you've read the tutorial on valgrind.org (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.interpret)? If you've read that and still have questions, why not ask specific questions here on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Tim Martin: Basically, when I ran it this time, I got an "Invalid write of size 8". I know what that means. However the next line (which I think is supposed to tell me where the error is) says, "at 0x80488A5: main (in /home/rkappiyo/Dropbox/xingResearch/finalMatlab/getParams)", which to me meant nothing other than the error was somewhere in my code.

Comment: Opening a whole new question for this issue with valgrind would be better than posting it at the bottom of a long comment thread. That way other people can benefit from reading it as well. The short answer is that you definitely need to compile with debug symbols (`-g` flag) to get useful locations out of Valgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really find this way of allocating 2-D matrices annoying, so I wrote a simple C procedure to allocate and initialize a 2-D array with a single malloc() call, so you can release the memory with a single free() call.  (Note, this could be extended/modified to use new char[...])

```
/* set up the memory for a 2D matrix with entries of size "size" */
void** matrix2D(long rows, long columns, long size)
{
    long    i;
    unsigned long long      row_size = (unsigned long long)columns * (unsigned long long)size;
    unsigned long long      data_size = ((unsigned long long)rows * (unsigned long long)columns + 1) * (unsigned long long)size;
    unsigned long long      pointer_size = (unsigned long long)rows * sizeof(void*);
    void**  result;

    if ( (result = (void**)malloc((size_t)(data_size + pointer_size))) == NULL ) {
            return NULL;
    }

    // take the first bit for a vector pointing to the m_pData for each row
    char* pdata = (char*)result + pointer_size;
    if ((unsigned long)pdata % size) {
      pdata += size - (unsigned long)pdata % size;
    }

    // for each row, set up the pointer to its m_pData
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            result[i] = (void*)pdata;
            pdata += row_size;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you could create each of your matrices using the single line, e.g.:

```
double** I = (double**)matrix2D(size, size, sizeof(double));
```

and they could be freed using, e.g.:

```
free(I);
```

Much simpler.  Also, then the matrix data values are contiguous, so for example if you create an array of integers and you want to initialize them all to zero, you could do:

```
int** array = (int**)matrix2D(height, width, sizeof(int));
memset(array, 0, height * width * sizeof(int));
```

or, to initialize it to a given (non-zero) value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height * width; ++i)
    array[i] = value;
```